Can't the multiple-value return of a function be attributed to multiple global variables? If not, what's the best alternative?
The following doesn't work. How to fix it or what's the best alternative?
var float avgBuyPrice = na
var float safetyTradeSize = na
var float safetyTradePrice = na

recalculate() =>
   _avgBuyPrice = strategy.position_avg_price
   _safetyTradeSize = strategy.position_size * 2
   _safetyTradePrice = _avgBuyPrice * (1 - safetyTrade)
   [_avgBuyPrice, _safetyTradeSize, _safetyTradePrice]

if (condition)
   [avgBuyPrice, safetyTradeSize, safetyTradePrice] := recalculate()


No, this is not yet possible.
As a workaround, store the values in temp variables and assign them to the global variables on the next line.
if (condition)
    [temp_avgBuyPrice, temp_safetyTradeSize, temp_safetyTradePrice] = recalculate()
    avgBuyPrice := temp_avgBuyPrice, safetyTradeSize := temp_safetyTradeSize, safetyTradePrice := temp_safetyTradePrice

